# Twilio - The requested resource not found error. while transferring number between sub accounts

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am using this sample code to transfer a number from one sub account to another sub account. (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts)

```
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACmastersid"; 
$token = "mastertoken"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

// Get an object from its sid. If you do not have a sid,
// check out the list resource examples on this page
$number = $client->account->incoming_phone_numbers-  >get("PN2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$number->update(array(
    "AccountSid" => "AC00000000000000000000000000000002"
));
echo $number->phone_number;
```

I am getting this error:

The requested resource /2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxx/IncomingPhoneNumbers/PNxxxxxxxxxxx.json was not found

It is not clear what is the issue with the code.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the account sid of the account that already owns the number or the one that you're moving it to?

Comment: As per documentation, the master account can transfer the number between accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine. You need to get the phone number object from the account you are moving from and then update the account sid.

```
// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACmastersid"; 
$token = "mastertoken"; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$account = $client->accounts->get( "AC00000000000000000000000000000001");
$number = $account->incoming_phone_numbers->get($phonesid);
$number->update(array(
"AccountSid" => "AC00000000000000000000000000000002"));
echo $number->phone_number;
```